# Php outputs same results no matter what

Tags: php, sql

Ok so basically I am having problems with outputting results from a search facility.

So let's say for example I search and I select a hotel with 'hotel_id' = 4 instead it always outputs results with 'hotel_id' = 1 no matter what I select. The search facility searches through name of hotel and guest's surname's and which ever is selected it should output anything that matches it, and that should be guests details, bookings that they made and hotels they have chosen.

My search facility looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <form action = "index.php" method="get">
        <input type = "submit" name = "mainpage" value = "Main Page" class = "submitbut" id = "but1" />
    </form>
</div>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type = "text" name = "search" id = "searching" />
    <input type = "submit" name = "data_submit" value = "Search" id = "scan" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['mainpage'])){
    header("Location:mainpage.php");
exit;
}
if (isset($_POST["data_submit"])){
$search_term = $_POST['search'];
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 
    'root'
    );
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotel
                       INNER JOIN booking
                        ON hotel.hotel_id=booking.hotel_id
                        INNER JOIN guest
                        ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                        WHERE name LIKE :search_term");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%'.$search_term. '%');
$stmt->execute();
echo
"<table><tr>  
<th>Hotels Matched</th>
</tr>";
while($hotel = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo
"<tr>"."<td>"."<a href='details.php?name=".$hotel['name']."'>".$hotel['name']."</a>"."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM guest
                       INNER JOIN booking
                       ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                       INNER JOIN hotel
                       On booking.hotel_id=hotel.hotel_id
                       WHERE guest.last_name LIKE :search_term");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%'.$search_term. '%');
$stmt->execute();
echo
"<table><tr>  
<th>Guests Matched</th>
</tr>";
while($hotel = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo
"<tr>"."<td>"."<a href='details.php?name=".$hotel['first_name']."'>".$hotel['last_name']."</a>"."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
$conn = NULL;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And my results are printed on another page, and it's code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <form action = "index.php" method="get">
        <input type = "submit" name = "mainpage" value = "Main Page" class = "submitbut" id = "but1" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 
    'root'
    );
if(!isset($_GET['name']))
{
    echo "You shouldn't have got to this page";
    exit;
}
$name = $_GET['name'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE name=$name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':name',$name);
$stmt->execute();
echo
"<table><tr>  
<th>hotel_id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>postcode</th>
<th>town</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>rating</th>
<th>image</th></tr>";
while($hotel=$stmt->fetch());
{
    echo
"<td>". $hotel['hotel_id']."</td>".
"<td>". $hotel['name']."</td>".
"<td>". $hotel['address']."</td>".
"<td>". $hotel['postcode']."</td>".
"<td>". $hotel['town']."</td>".
"<td>". $hotel['description']."</td>".
"<td>". $hotel['rating']."</td>".
"<td>"."<img src='". $hotel['image']. "'>"."</td>"."</tr>";
//$variable = $hotel['hotel_id'];
}
echo "</table>";
/*
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE hotel_id=$variable";
echo
"<table><tr>
<th>hotel_id</th>
<th>guest_id</th>
<th>payment-type</th>
<th>amount</th>
<th>nights</th></tr>";
$results2 = $conn->query($query2);
    if($variable = $results2->fetch()) { echo
"<tr>"."<td>".$variable['hotel_id']."</td>".
"<td>". $variable['guest_id']."</td>".
"<td>". $variable['payment-type']."</td>".
"<td>". "&pound;".$variable['amount']."</td>".
"<td>". $variable['nights']."</td>"."</tr>";
$guest_id = $variable['guest_id'];
    }
echo "</table>";

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM guest WHERE guest_id=$guest_id";
echo
"<table><tr>
<th>guest_id</th>
<th>first_name</th>
<th>last_name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>postcode</th>
<th>town</th></tr>";
$results3 =$conn->query($query3);
    while($guest = $results3->fetch()) { echo
"<tr>"."<td>".$guest['guest_id']."</td>".
"<td>". $guest['first_name']."</td>".
"<td>". $guest['last_name']."</td>".
"<td>". $guest['address']."</td>".
"<td>". $guest['postcode']."</td>".
"<td>". $guest['town']."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
*/
$conn=NULL;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am stuck on this for days now so please help me to make this work and also if there are any ways to reduce and not duplicating same code all over again.

Thanks for any efforts ;)

Please note I am not allowed to use javascript

Comment: Certainly an error here `$query = "SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE name=$name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':name',$name);` ~ there ought to be a placeholder in the sql called `:name` rather than the actual variable and another error here `while($hotel=$stmt->fetch());
{` ~ there is a semi-colon there that shouldn't be. Inside the loop there is no opening `<tr>` tag

Comment: Well the column in a database is called "name"

Comment: So the query is basically saying then `where column_name=column_name` ?

Comment: well $name is retrieved or should be retrieved from previous page and stored in that variable, and then comparision between that value and a value in a database should be done and if they both match output the results

Answer (score 0):

I changed the pieces identified as probably incorrect and did some tidying up - looks like it should work, certainly there should be nothing wrong with the selection of records based upon the search

```
<!--

Search ( assumed to be index.php )
----------------------------------
As this page displays results from the search I assume that this
is "index.php" and that the form `POST`s back to this page.

-->
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hotel Database Search</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="mainpage" value="Main Page" class="submitbut" id="but1" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="searching" />
        <input type="submit" name="data_submit" value="Search" id="scan" />
    </form>

    <?php
        /* This is liable to cause an error: headers should not be sent after any output */
        if( isset( $_GET['mainpage'] ) ) exit( header( "Location: mainpage.php" ) );

        if ( isset( $_POST["data_submit"] ) ){

            $search_term = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['search'] ) );
            $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 'root' );

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `hotel` h
                                    INNER JOIN `booking` b ON h.`hotel_id`=b.`hotel_id`
                                    INNER JOIN `guest` g ON g.`guest_id`=b.`guest_id`
                                    WHERE `name` LIKE :search_term;");
            $stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%' . $search_term . '%');
            $stmt->execute();


            echo "<table><tr><th>Hotels Matched</th></tr>";

            while( $rs= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) {
                echo "<tr><td><a href='details.php?name=".$rs->name."'>".$rs->name."</a></td></tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";




            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `guest` g
                                   INNER JOIN `booking` b  ON g.`guest_id`=b.`guest_id`
                                   INNER JOIN `hotel` On b.`hotel_id`=h.`hotel_id`
                                   WHERE g.`last_name` LIKE :search_term;");

            $stmt->bindValue( ':search_term', '%'.$search_term.'%' );
            $stmt->execute();


            echo "<table><tr><th>Guests Matched</th></tr>";

            while( $rs= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) {
                echo "<tr><td><a href='details.php?name=".$rs->first_name."'>".$rs->last_name."</a></td</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";
            $conn = NULL;
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>


<!--

Results ( assumed to be "details.php" )
---------------------------------------
I again assume that this is the details page and this is linked to
via the results found on "index.php"

-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="mainpage" value="Main Page" class="submitbut" id="but1" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        if( !isset( $_GET['name'] ) ) exit("You shouldn't have got to this page");

        $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 'root'  );
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        $query="SELECT * FROM `hotel` WHERE `name`=:name;";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindValue( ':name', $name );
        $stmt->execute();

        echo
            "<table>
                <tr>  
                    <th>hotel_id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>address</th>
                    <th>postcode</th>
                    <th>town</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>rating</th>
                    <th>image</th>
            </tr>";

            while( $rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>{$rs->hotel_id}</td>
                    <td>{$rs->name}</td>
                    <td>{$rs->address}</td>
                    <td>{$rs->postcode}</td>
                    <td>{$rs->town}</td>
                    <td>{$rs->description}</td>
                    <td>{$rs->rating}</td>
                    <td><img src='{$rs->image}'></td>
                </tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
        $conn=NULL;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick however now it only searches through hotel names, but ignores the part with searching by guest's last name for some reason

Comment: Surely though the search criteria that you use to search for hotels is not likely to return the guest's `last_name` is it?

Comment: well the thing is I am required to provide more than 1 search option so in this one I am giving a option to search by hotel or by guest - to find their booking so it does have to search by last_name and then output their details and hotel details they have booked edit:// there is even code in a search page that says to look by last_name too

Comment: Perhaps you misundserstood what I meant or I have - but suppose you search for a hotel called `"Hilton"` then you would match hotels quite easily and perhaps also `"Paris Hilton"` as a `guest`, but if you search for `"Ibis"` it is unlikely that there will be a guest with "Ibis" as their surname / `last name`

Comment: Oh I get what you mean, but if I input "W" it should output me hotels and surnames that have "W" but it doesn't, well it does but only for hotels and not the surnames, and 5 surnames contains W so I should get an output